# split strings with uppercase

Tags: java, string

I have some strings that I want to split them word by word. They are in different formats like:

```
THIS-IS-MY-STRING
ThisIsMyString
This_Is_My_String
This is my string
```

I use:

```
String[] x = str1.split("(?=[A-Z])|[_]|[-]|[ ]");
```

But there are some problems:

1. some elements in x array will be empty
2. for the first string I want “THIS” but the result of split is “T”, “H”, “I”, “S”

How should I change split to reach my purpose? Could you please help me?

Comment: `[A-Z]` matches any uppercase character. So `THIS` will be split after each character, thus `T`,`H`,`I`,`S`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to include look-behind as well, here you go:

```
String[] x = str1.split("([-_ ]|(?<=[^-_ A-Z])(?=[A-Z]))");
```

`[-_ ]` means `-` or `_` or space.

`(?<=[^-_ A-Z])` means the previous character isn't a `-`, `_`, space, or `A-Z`.

`(?=[A-Z])` means the next character is `A-Z`.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

**EDIT:**

Unfortunately there is no way (I know of) that you can use `split` to split `_CITY_ABC` while avoiding `_CITY` or an empty string.

You can however only process the first and last string if not empty, but this is not ideal.

For this I suggest `Matcher`:

```
String str1 = "_CityCITY_";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z][a-z]+(?=[A-Z]|$)|[A-Za-z]+(?=[-_ ]|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str1);
while (m.find())
   System.out.println(m.group());
```

Comment: @user1832388 Remember to [upvote or accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168143/206447) answers you find helpful.

Comment: There is another problem, I have an string like _CITY, and the result of String[] x = str1.split("([-_ ]|(?<=[^-_ A-Z])(?=[A-Z]))");
is: "_CITY", I mean that "_" is the first character of my string, How should I change split parameter to omit "_"?

Comment: @user1832388 For future reference, surround statements with ` so special characters are displayed. I edited my answer for what I think you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex.Split().  The first param is the string to split and the second string would be your regular expression.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Sure, Dukeling really nailed it though.